# How to pass the value from one asp page to another asp page using queryString?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, query-string, request.querystring, querystringparameter

How to pass the value from one asp.net page to another asp.net web page using queryString.It means **test1.aspx and test2.aspx** are two web pages.

In test1.aspx, i have the string value,

```
string abc="stackoverflow";
```

if i use like this

**Request.Redirect("test2.aspx?numbers=" + abc);** .It will not work.If i use like this i cant able to get abc value in test2.aspx page.

```
how to get this abc values into the test2.aspx?
```

Comment: Did it work for you now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of

```
Request.Redirect("test2.aspx?numbers=" + abc);
```

Use

```
Response.Redirect("test2.aspx?numbers=" + abc);
```

To recieve the QueryString value in the `test2.aspx` page you can use

```
Request.QueryString["numbers"];
```